# Commutator of covariant derivative for rank 2 tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, curvature

I am a newbie at tensor notation and I have been told to prove the identity

> $$ (\nabla_a\nabla_b - \nabla_b\nabla_a)X^a_{\ \ \ b}=- R^e_{\ \ \ bcd}X^a_{\ \ \ e}+ R^a_{\ \ \ ecd}X^e_{\ \ \ b} $$

I am aware of the definition of the Riemman tensor
$(\nabla_a\nabla_b - \nabla_b\nabla_a)X_c= R_{abc}^{\quad d}X_{d}$ and using the metric connection $\nabla_a g_{bc}=0$ I have already shown
$(\nabla_a\nabla_b - \nabla_b\nabla_a)X^c= -R_{abd}^{\quad c}X^{d}$
but still I cannot figure out how to obtain the first one... :(

I am working torsion-free and I am aware of the formula that relates the Riemman tensor with the Christoffel symbols.

PS:  My guess is to go with $X^a_{\ \ \ b} = v^a w_b$ but not sure if that is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

> PS: My guess is to go with $X^a_{\ \ \ b} = v^a w_b$ but not sure if
> that is the right way to go.

It is. Schematically:
$$
R\sim\left[\nabla,\nabla\right]
$$
Any derivative worth that name satisfies:
$$
\nabla\left(uv\right)=\left(\nabla u\right)v+u\nabla v
$$
Covariant derivatives act like,
$$
\nabla\sim\partial+\Gamma
$$
for contravariant vectors.
$$
\nabla\sim\partial-\Gamma
$$
for covariant vectors.

Finally, the tangent space at a point is a vector space. Is that enough of a clue?

Comment: Okay, I think that shed some light, thanks!